# How can I pass object-specific values to a function from objects created in a loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, tkinter

I have searched deeply for a solution to this problem, but, being new to Python and tkinter, it is difficult to find solutions to problems in a language you are largely unfamiliar with. I hope this is not a repeat question.

Suppose I create a series of buttons in tkinter, each of which will sequentially display a letter of the alphabet, defined as such:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as alphabet
from tkinter import Button
blockLetterButtons = []
for i in range(0,26):
    blockLetterButtons.append(Button(competitorSelectionFrame, 
    text=alphabet[i], command=some_function(alphabet[i])))
```

Somewhere below this in the `for` loop is a `.grid(...)` for all of these.

The function that is being referenced in the `command` attribute is as the following:

```
def some_function(letter):
    print(letter)
```

So I recognize two problems with my code:

1. The function in the `command` attribute is executing immediately upon running the code, because I am specifying a function call rather than a function name.
2. Even if that was the proper way to call the function with a parameter, using `alphabet[i]` wouldn't work, because it would pass whatever the value of `i` is upon click, and not whatever `i` was upon execution of the `for` loop.

So my questions are the following:

1. How can I specify a function in the `command` attribute and pass to that function with a parameter?
2. How can I specify that parameter to be the letter of the alphabet specific to that button, without defining a button explicitly for every letter?

I am fairly certain I could use a list comprehension to solve the second problem, perhaps a dictionary with the key equal to the letter and the value equal to the button, but then I still wouldn't know how to get the key value from the button on its own.

Comment: `command=lambda i=i: some_function(alphabet[i])` is the idiomatic solution.  The lambda makes a function that can be called later without needing any parameters; the parameter `i` with a default captures the value of the outer `i` at the moment the lambda is defined, so each button gets its distinct value.

Comment: That is certainly the idiomatic way, and much more concise than my answer. May I suggest posting that as an answer yourself?

Comment: @jasonharper This solution worked perfectly, thank you. So the lambda generates a function for each Button, and does so for the current instance of i in the loop. What exactly does i=i do? Is that the parameter for the function created by lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a higher order function (a function that returns a function). To demonstrate, I will not use tkinter but the principle is the same:

```
In [25]: def some_func_maker(letter):
    ...:     def some_func():
    ...:         print(letter)
    ...:     return some_func
    ...:

In [26]: buttons = []

In [27]: from string import ascii_uppercase as alphabet

In [28]: for i in range(26):
    ...:     buttons.append(some_func_maker(alphabet[i]))
    ...:

In [29]: for b in buttons: b()
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

Note, you can inline this if you don't want to keep a `some_func_maker` around using a lambda:

```
In [37]: buttons = []
    ...: for c in alphabet:
    ...:     buttons.append(
    ...:         (lambda x: lambda: some_function(x))(c)
    ...:     )
    ...:

In [38]: for b in buttons: b()
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

A common trick is that is less verbose is to use a default-argument with your lambda, however, I consider this more hacky, although it is quite common in Python:

```
In [43]: buttons = []
    ...: for c in alphabet:
    ...:     buttons.append(
    ...:         lambda x=c: some_function(x)
    ...:     )
    ...:

In [44]: buttons[0]()
A

In [45]: buttons[1]()
B

In [46]: buttons[-1]()
Z
```

Note also, it is consider an antipattern to use `for i in range(n): some_iterable[i]` when you can simply iterate over the iterable instead. Usually, you just want the actual value, so you just do `for x in some_iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

[*Currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is the practice of passing some arguments to a function to produce a new function which can be called later but "remembers" its earlier arguments. You can use this technique to pass the state.

```
def some_function(letter):
    def f():
        print(letter)
    return f

...

command = some_function(alphabet[i])
```

So `some_function(alphabet[i])()` would call the function, but only using one set of parentheses simply stores the value for later.

Comment: [`functools.partial` already exists for this purpose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). `command=partial(print, alphabet[i])` would work without defining new currying utility functions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not currying, but partial application, [I believe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application), but I frequently get the two confused anyway...